How can I configure select2 for the following nested array
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Select2 Example</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="term-options">
        <label for="term-select">Select Terms:</label>
        <select id="term-select" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px !important; margin-bottom: 20px !important; display: block;" multiple="multiple"></select>
        <button id="clear-search">Clear Search</button>
    </div>
    <div id="xml-content"></div>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var jsonData = {
                "ICD10CM.index": {
                    mainTerm: [
                        {
                            title: "Aarskog's syndrome",
                            code: "Q87.19",
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Abderhalden-Kaufmann-Lignac syndrome(cystinosis)",
                            code: "E72.04",
                            _level: "1",
                            term: [
                                {
                                    title: "in",
                                    _level: "2",
                                    term: [
                                        {
                                            title: "diseases classified elsewhere",
                                            code: "I68.2",
                                            _level: "3",
                                        },
                                        {
                                            title: "systemic lupus erythematosus",
                                            code: "M32.19",
                                            _level: "3",
                                        },
                                    ],
                                    
                                }
                            ],
                            
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Abdomen, abdominal",
                            seeAlso: "condition",
                            term: [
                                {
                                    title: "acute",
                                    code: "R10.0",
                                    _level: "1",
                                },
                                {
                                    title: "angina",
                                    code: "K55.1",
                                    _level: "1",
                                },
                                {
                                    title: "muscle deficiency syndrome",
                                    code: "Q79.4",
                                    _level: "1",
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                },
            };

            var mainTerms = jsonData["ICD10CM.index"].mainTerm;

            function populateSelect2(data) {
                var options = data.map(function (item) {
                    return { id: item.title, text: item.title };
                });
                $("#term-select").empty().select2({
                    placeholder: "Select terms",
                    multiple: true,
                    tags: false,
                    data: options,
                });
            }

            function initializeSelect2() {
                populateSelect2(mainTerms);

                $("#term-select").on("select2:select", function (e) {
                    var selectedTerm = e.params.data.text;
                    var term = mainTerms.find((term) => term.title === selectedTerm);
                    console.log("Selected term:", selectedTerm);
                    console.log("Term object:", term);
                    if (term && term.term) {
                        console.log("Sub-terms:", term.term);
                        var subTerms = term.term.map(function (subTerm) {
                            return {
                                id: subTerm.title,
                                text: subTerm.title,
                            };
                        });
                        console.log("Sub-terms options:", subTerms);
                        $("#term-select").empty().select2({
                            placeholder: "Select terms",
                            multiple: true,
                            tags: false,
                            data: subTerms,
                        });

                        // Add the selected main term to the options so it remains visible
                        var mainTermOption = new Option(
                            selectedTerm,
                            selectedTerm,
                            true,
                            true
                        );
                        $("#term-select").append(mainTermOption).trigger("change");

                    }

                    // Display selected term code
                    if (term && term.code) {
                        $("#xml-content").html("<p>" + term.code + "</p>");
                    } else {
                        $("#xml-content").html("");
                    }
                });

                $("#term-select").on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
                    var remainingTerms = $("#term-select").select2("data");

                    if (remainingTerms.length === 0) {
                        populateSelect2(mainTerms);
                        $("#xml-content").html(""); // Clear the content div
                    }
                });

                $("#term-select").on("change", function () {
                    var selectedOptions = $("#term-select").select2("data");
                    var codes = selectedOptions.map(function (option) {
                        var term = mainTerms.find((term) => term.title === option.text) || {};
                        return term.code || option.id;
                    });

                    $("#xml-content").html("<p>" + codes.join(", ") + "</p>");
                });

                $("#clear-search").on("click", function () {
                    $("#term-select").val(null).trigger("change");
                    $("#xml-content").html("");
                });
            }

            initializeSelect2();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Main term is my main array and all objects inside that should be consider as level 0
On selecting level 0 I want it to show only its objects which they are level 1. Once selection on level 1 they will only show level 2.
Is it possible to do this? My code couldn't able to work on nested. Any help would be highly appreciated
